# Do calculations with bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

in my web page, I have some date fields and they are assigned with `Bootstrap datepicker`. In a `javascript` function I need to get the date of a field called `onBookingDate`. I can get it like this.

```
var on_BookingDate =  jQuery('#datepick_onBooking').val();
```

Then I need to add 8 months to it and then compare the new date value with another date value which is retrieved using the above method. This is the code I used. (All the dates are in the form of `dd-mm-yyyy`)

```
var on_BookingDate =  jQuery('#datepick_onBooking').val();
var dateArray = on_BookingDate.split("-");
//dateArray[1] contains the month value

var dateObj = new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1] - 1, dateArray[0]);
dateObj.setMonth(dateObj.getMonth() + 8);
var intFreeLastDate = dateObj.getDate() + "-" + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dateObj.getFullYear();
```

In order to compare dates, they have to be time values. For that

1. `.datepicker('getDate')`
2. `getTime()`

have to be used. But when I tried

```
var int_free_last_date = intFreeLastDate.datepicker('getDate');
alert("int free last date get date = "+int_free_last_date);
```

I get following error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Why is this? and how to fix this. Isn't the `int_free_last_date` in date format required??

**JS FIddle** http://jsfiddle.net/Lnmvc5ao/

Comment: What line is causing that error? Can you make a JSFiddle for us to use as an example?

Comment: line is `var int_free_last_date = intFreeLastDate.datepicker('getDate');`

Comment: What does `console.log(intFreeLastDate)` return if called right above that line?

Comment: it returns a date in the required form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the issue. This line:

```
var int_free_last_date = intFreeLastDate.datepicker('getDate');
```

Is using the `.datepicker('getDate')` function wrong. When you call it like that, it's trying to get a date value from an HTML form element. For example, if you called:

```
jQuery('#datepick_onBooking').datepicker('getDate');
```

It would return the date value present in the `('#datepick_onBooking')` element's datepicker. If `intLastFreeDate` was something like `01-02-2015`, that line would be equivalent to:

```
var int_free_last_date = 01-02-2015.datepicker('getDate');
```

Which, as you can imagine, doesn't work as `01-02-2015` is `undefined`.

I think you're close to your solution, you just need to format your already present dates into a time value and compare them:

```
var on_BookingDateTime = on_BookingDate.getTime();
var lastFreeDateTime = intLastFreeDate.getTime();
// Compare em however you would.
```

Hopefully that helps!

**EDIT**

Since both `on_BookingDate` and `intFreeLastDate` are valid date string `dd-mm-yyyy`, you can split them by their `-` and make a `date` object out of them, then call `getTime()` on those objects, followed by the comparison.

```
var temp1= on_BookingDate.split("-"); 
var temp2 = intFreeLastDate.split("-");
// [0] is day, [1] is month, [2] is year.

var date1 = new Date(temp1[2], (temp1[1] - 1), temp1[0]);
var date2 = new Date(temp2[2], (temp2[1] - 1), temp2[0]);

var time1 = date1.getTime();
var time2 = date2.getTime();

// Then compare them!
```

[JSFiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnmvc5ao/3/)

Comment: to use `.getTime();` we have to use `.datepicker('getDate')`. then only we can use `.getTime();`. Isn't it?

Comment: Hmm. Ok I need to know something, what are the exact values of both `onBookingDate` and `intLastFreeDate`?

Comment: say `onBookingDate` is 01-01-205 and `intFreeLastDate` is 01-09-2015. I added the js fiddle

Comment: Ok, that's good. I'll edit it how you can use `.getTime()` on those dates :)